# How do I add an Object List named buffer into a nested Object List without affecting my values after calling buffer.Clear();

Tags: c#, list, reference, buffer, addition

I want to add a `List<Object> buffer` to `List<List<Object> output` with `output.Add(buffer)`.

But when I execute `buffer.Clear();` immediately after I added it to my `output` list the list of objects in `output` is suddenly empty.

How can I keep my values in `output` while clearing my `buffer` in every iteration, and why is this even happening?

```
 List<List<Tris>> faceSort()
{
    List<List<Tris>> output = new List<List<Tris>>(); //Output sorted list
    List<Tris> mod = constructModel(); //construct new model, gets smaller
    List<Tris> buffer = new List<Tris>();
    Vector3[] currentFace = new Vector3 [3];
    Vector3 normal = new Vector3();
    while (mod.Any())
    {
        currentFace[0] = mod[0].v1;
        currentFace[1] = mod[0].v2;
        currentFace[2] = mod[0].v3;
        normal = mod[0].normale;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < mod.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Vector3.Distance(normal,mod[i].normale)<= 0.1 && surfCheck(currentFace, mod[i].v1))
            {
                buffer.Add(mod[i]);
                mod.Remove(mod[i]);
                i--;
            }

        }
        output.Add(buffer);
        buffer.Clear();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Here is the Debugger after `output.Add(buffer)` and before hitting `Clear();`
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS4pU.png)

And here after executing `buffer.Clear();`
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voMRa.png)

Comment: try to add to buffer `.ToList()`, like `output.Add(buffer.ToList());` Or delete `buffer.Clear();` and before `for`, instantiate the buffer list.

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked for me in this case!